# checking arguments in a shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement, arguments

I'm having a surprising large amount of trouble finding a guide on this.

what's wrong with this shell script:

```
if ["$1" == "-t"]
then
        echo "t"
elif ["$1" == "-r"]
then
        echo "r"
fi
```

It's supposed to be a very simple test.  if the argument is `-t`, do one thing, if it's `-r` do the other.

Comment: check it with http://www.shellcheck.net/ for the basic errors. It should be trivial! Hint: `[ ]` (<strike>statements</strike>) commands need spaces around the brackets.

Comment: That's it.  Add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @fedorqui (Yeah, this is a nit, but ...) `[]` is *not* a statement. `[` is a command.  Too many people get confused thinking that `[` is part of the shell grammar, and calling it a "statement" reinforces that error.

Comment: Never chain `if/else` like this: `case $1 in; -t) echo t;; -r) echo r;; esac`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is a command (see it with `man [` or directly to `man test`). Thus, you need spaces around them in order to be interpreted properly:

```
if [ "$1" == "-t" ]
then
        echo "t"
elif [ "$1" == "-r" ]
then
        echo "r"
fi
```

Or better use POSIX compliant `=`: `if [ "$1" = "-t" ] ...`.

#### See interesting comments by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) and [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) below.

Comment: If we're going to try to be pedantically correct, might be preferable to use the (POSIX-compliant) string comparison operator `=` rather than the extension `==`.

Comment: Another nit: `[]` is also not a command!  `[` is a command, and `]` is the last argument to it.  It's probably easier to say `[]` is a command, though, but...let the reader beware!